# Is it possible to purchase a new app via In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to purchase a new app from inApp Purchase in iOS, i know that i can provide a update item in Apple server or in my own server and can provide this as an inApp purchase, but by doing so it will be a same apps update or with added feature buying from InApp Purchase.
But My doubt is, ***is it possible to buy a separate app say,from a Travel app, purchase an game app through InApp Purchase?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can install an app trough another app - TestFlight does it for example.

But this kind of app will not pass the AppStore revision if you want to 
use inApp purchase mechanism - downloading code is not allowed by Apple.

So while it technically is possible - it just won't go trough.

And if you want to implement your own payment processing: they won't allow an app that acts as an app store.